# Average algorithm with complexity less than O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Is there any algorithm to find average of `n` values that has a complexity less than `O(n)`?

Comment: So you want to count the average of `n` numbers without knowing all of them?

Comment: As biziclop points out, you need to relax the goal. E.g., numbers are in a fixed range [0,1], and you only want to approximate the average, and you have access to randomness or something. Otherwise if you don't read every single number, and the numbers are unbounded in size, then obviously that number can change the average arbitrarily so no approximation is possible.

Comment: I was thinking about some sort of caching. In the beginning the algo. needs O(n), but then the algorithm can approximate the average when the value of one element has changed.

Comment: Even if you had a data structure that held the running total of the numbers and the amount of numbers input into it. The fact that you have inserted `n` numbers is still `O(n)`

Comment: You should expand upon your question to include how you intend to use this. Sounds like you might have a data set where you can calculate the average ahead of time, but then it changes and you want to know the average after changes. For each element changed, if you know what the value of was before and after you can simply update the stored total and that requires `O(1)` per change, which ends up being  `O(N + k)` if you have `k` changes, rather than `O(k * N)` if you recompute the average for each change.

Comment: Ah, I think you want online averaging! So in other words, you want an algorithm that can update the average as new data comes in without having to look at the old data. That's possible. (You could even _throw out_ the old data.) I'll post an answer if you modify your question to reflect that.

Comment: If you have at least `n` CPU cores available (say an infinity of them), then the time complexity will be O(1) doing some // programming.. And within the same amount of fantasy, using a quantum computer, you request the calculation to be done in the past, and in O(1) the result comes :-)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like you actually want an algorithm that can calculate an average based on *new* data without having to look at the old data. In other words, what you really want is an *online* algorithm that isn't O(n^2).

You can have that, quite easily. There are online algorithms for [variance and standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) too. The basic formula for means is dead simple:

```
new_mean = old_mean + (next_val - old_mean) / n
```

It's easy to derive too. Suppose `A_n` is an n-item array, and `A_(n-1)` is the same array without the last element (`a_n`). We want to know the value of `x` such that `mean(A_(n-1)) + x = mean(A_n)`.

```
x == mean(A_n) - mean(A_(n-1))
```

So far so good, but this seems to require that we know the very value that we seek, `mean(A_n)`. Fortunately, we can find that out using only information we already have. We know that `mean(A_n) = sum(A_n) / n`, and it doesn't take much thought to see that `sum(A_n) = mean(A_(n-1)) * (n - 1) + a_n`

```
x = sum(A_n) / n - mean(A_(n-1))
x = (mean(A_(n-1)) * (n - 1) + a_n) / n - mean(A_(n-1))
```

Now substitute the original value of `x` in:

```
mean(A_n) - mean(A_(n-1)) = 
    (mean(A_(n-1)) * (n - 1) + a_n) / n - mean(A_(n-1))
```

The `- mean(A_(n-1))` terms cancel out:

```
mean(A_n) = (mean(A_(n-1)) * (n - 1) + a_n) / n
```

And all that remains is to redistribute terms:

```
mean(A_n) = (n * mean(A_(n-1)) - mean(A_(n-1)) + a_n) / n
mean(A_n) = mean(A_(n-1)) - mean(A_(n-1)) / n + a_n / n
mean(A_n) = mean(A_(n-1)) + a_n / n - mean(A_(n-1)) / n
mean(A_n) = mean(A_(n-1)) + (a_n - mean(A_(n-1))) / n
new_mean = old_mean + (next_val - old_mean) / n
```

Comment: In this case why not keeping the sum of the previous items and do `new_mean = (sum += item) / ++n`.. (The only drawback is if *sum* becomes too big). But this way, for floating point numbers, accuracy is better (as the previous mean / division result is never reused).

Comment: @ringø, yes, maintaining a sum would be better in some cases. But I think it would depend on a lot of things. If the sum is a sum of integer values, then the benefit is obvious. But for a mean of many large floating point numbers, I bet this is better -- once the value gets very large, the rounding error would become more significant than the accumulated numerical error.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you only need an approximation, just sample a subset of the numbers and average those.

If you can assume the distribution of the numbers (eg. Gaussian) you can also calculate how many you need to sample to get an average that is within the *correct* value to a given accuracy.

Comment: could you please provide an example in your answer ? This is an interesting concept.

Comment: As an addition, the most straightforward way to create the subset is by taking a (constant) fraction of the original data which is still technically just O(n). You would need to take something like up to the log or square root of the total number of elements to make it less than O(n).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible without knowing any meta-information about the numbers. The reason for this is that you have to at least read all the numbers and reading `n` numbers is `O(n)`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I was thinking about some sort of caching. In the beginning the algo. needs O(n), but then the algorithm can approximate the average when the value of one element has changed

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you have extra information.

For example. If you **already** have the items divided into k bins **B**1...**B**k, with bin values **V**1...**V**k then the average will be approximately **M** = sum(i=1..k)[**B**i***V**i]/n. This is O(1).

Alternately. If you **already** know the average value of the first n-1 items is **M**old, then the average when adding an n-th item with item value **V**n is **M** = (**M**old*(n-1)+**V**n)/n. This is also O(1).

Alternately, if the items were **already** sorted **and** could only take some k distinct values **V**1..**V**k, (for example - an array {**V**1,**V**1,**V**1..**V**1,**V**2,**V**2..**V**2,**V**3..**V**3...**V**k,**V**k} then it  would be possible to use a binary search to find the number of items with each value **V**k, then calculate the average as in the binned example above. This, I think, is O(k*ln(n)).

There may be other possibilities...

But if you just have a list or array of n values **V**1..**V**n, I don't believe there is anything better than the standard method **M** = sum(i=1..n)[**V**i]/n. Which is O(n)